# Decode Base64 into jpg images

Tags: hadoop

We have logfiles that i.e contain Base64 encoded images. I would like to process these logfiles and extract the base64 encoded "stuff", decode it and store it as "real" image files.

I have been searching for how to do this at it seems as there is no way of producing an image file from hadoop, except for using Sequence*OutputFormat classes.

My question in short is, Is it possible to produce jpg files from the base64 encoded files from hadoop without writing a custom OutputFormat?

Kind regards /Johan

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with "custom OutputFormat", but this is what I do in my web app (not hadoop related in any way though). HTH.

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public static void storeImage(String imageBase64, String path) {
    imageBase64 = imageBase64.replace("\n", "");
    try {
        new BASE64Decoder().decodeBufferToByteBuffer(imageBase64);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(out);
        p.write(new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(imageBase64));
        p.flush();
        p.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error storing image.", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work on a normal machine but not on HDFS, hadoop as specialized api:s for that.